# Addition, Dimensions and O

Tags: forces, quantum-spin, dimensional-analysis

I have a glass of water in front of me. 

Selecting any particle in that glass.
 Is it possible for that particle to be in all positions ( NOT AT THE SAME TIME  ) that the water occupies in the glass?

There can be no change of state of matter. 
Maybe, and I say, maybe, Gravity can be broken down (to pieces).

Comment: As the Jedi say: May the force be with you

Comment: Why not? Diffusion happens.

Comment: Although it's not the same,  "paint" a particle in a single molecule  and beam it up close to the limit of change of state of matter and watch. If loop detected,  stop. Is every point in the "container " painted ? You will see a very interesting pattern in the "gaps".

Answer (score 2):

Technically I suppose so, but molecules in liquid (especially in a substance composed of hydrogen bonds like water) are quite "fixed" and don't move too much around. If it was a container full of water *vapor*, it would be a different story.

I'm not entirely sure what the content of the question has to do with the title, or with the tags, by the way.

Comment: I do not think that it can.